# Can't set Sender ID with AWS CLI for SMS via Amazon SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-sns

I am using following AWS CLI to set Sender ID, however I am still able to see random phone number is receiver message.

```
aws sns publish --message "hello" --phone-number +1-365-XXX-XXXX --message-attributes '{"AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID": { "DataType": "String","StringValue": "Airflow"}, "AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType": {"DataType": "String","StringValue": "Promotional"}}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Supported Regions and countries - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-supported-regions-countries.html) documentation page includes a table **showing which countries support Sender ID**.

The number you are using appears to be from the USA. The table does *not* show the USA as supporting Sender ID.

This is likely the reason why the Sender ID is not appearing for your recipients.